# onClick does not function inside a dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jquery code which generate a div dynamically

the problem is that the onclick function for the a tag does not calls the required function

Here is the code

```
$("#new").append('
    <ul class="#...#">
        <li>
            <a href="./d.html?n1='+item[0]+'&n2='+item[2]+'&n3='+item[3]+'">
                <input type="hidden" value='+item[0]+'>
                    <img style="height: 64px; width: 64px;" class="#...#"
                        src="image.png" width="40" height="40" />
                    <span class="#...#">
                        <b>'+item[0]+'</b>
                        '+item[1]+'......
                    </span>
            </a>
            <br />
            <div>
                <a onClick="insert();" href="#">
                    <i class="icon1"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="2.php?q='+q+'&n='+item[0]+'" id="icon2" name="icon2">
                    <i class="icon2"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
');
```

I am using the above code as an ajax success function

the ***a*** tag is not calling the *insert()* function
I searched for the error but could not find the

What am doing it wrong?
Thsnks in advance

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's "live" method: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: jQuery's "live" method : version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Comment: You can try putting the `insert()` function within `$(document).ready(function() { ..insert() function code here..  });`

Comment: @wild_nothing very much bad advice there.

Comment: As @wild_nothing mentionned. If you have written a function like `$('a').click(function(){...});` it will only takes effect on existing  `a` tags. You must use `.on()` (as .live() is deprecated) to bind an event on both existing and future elements.

Comment: I would suggest using event delegation

Comment: Can you still read your own code?

Comment: you have to use .On have a look here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I hope you could put it on a fiddle.

Comment: where is your insert method?

Comment: yep include inline event while appending elements - really good practice not

Comment: insert function is just an alert

Comment: Problem is something else.. this should work fine.. can you find any errors in error console

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript event delegation to separate concerns:

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', 'ul.someClass div a', function() {
        // insert() method logic goes here
    });
});
```

Second argument specifies the event target. This event is bind to the document's body so it's always present. Target DOM objects can be generated per AJAX at some point later or removed from the document. The actual target check happens when a user actually clicks something.

Also adding a class attribute to `<div>` or `<a>` in your code might help with readability. E.g.:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="btn-insert" onClick="insert();" href="#">
        <i class="icon1"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="2.php?q='+q+'&n='+item[0]+'" id="icon2" name="icon2">
        <i class="icon2"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Target attribute for jQuery `on()` method could then be simplified to just `'.btn-insert'`

Answer (score 0):

When you work with dynamic content I suggest you use DOM event delegation. The ideea is to add the listener on a parent of your dynamically added content

This explains how to do it and how it works

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class, such as "catchClick" to the element that you need to catch the click event of.

```
var linkToAdd = '<a class="catchClick" href="#">My link</a>';
var $linkToAdd = $(linkToAdd);
$('#new').append($linkToAdd);
```

Then the following code will setup handlers for clicks on that element.

It works because the click event is bubbled up the dom hierarchy to the document element. So you can attach a listener to the document element instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.catchClick', function(e) {
    // do your stuff here
    // you probably need to get a jquery reference to the element that was clicked:
    var $this = $(this);
    // you probably want to stop the event's default actions so we'll add this:
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the click event handler AFTER having appended new clickable items to the document, and subsequently after each time you append new clickable items to the document.